# Webpack 3, Extract Text plugin not resolving sass-loader includePaths

Tags: webpack, bourbon, sass-loader, extracttextwebpackplugin

I have this setup working on an older project using:

```
webpack@3.0.0
extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.1.2
```

I'm now trying on a new project so have upgraded to:

```
webpack@3.8.1
extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.1.
```

Webpack config is exactly the same but now I'm getting errors.

I'm using node-bourbon and I'm wanting to make it available across all my entries rather having to import it each time.

I have a SCSS file: stylesheets/tools/mixins/bourbon.scss that (should) simply import bourbon:
`@import 'bourbon';`

Then I'm using sass-resources-loader to make that (along with some other mixins) available across all modules (see config below).

webpack config:

`{
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            use: [
              ...
              {
                loader: "sass-loader",
                options: {
                  sourceMap: true,
                  includePaths: require('bourbon').includePaths
                }
              },
              {
                loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
                options: {
                  resources: [
                    './frontend/stylesheets/settings/*.scss',
                    './frontend/stylesheets/tools/**/*.scss'
                  ]
                },
              },
            ]
          })
        },`

However the import statement in the SCSS file is not resolving to node_modules, it tries to reference itself so I get this error:

`Module build failed:
    @import 'bourbon';
    ^
          An @import loop has been found:`

It seems the includePaths for node-bourbon are being ignored?

UPDATED:

I've managed to work around for now by referencing bourbon directly:
`@import '~bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/_bourbon';`

Not ideal, but it does the job.

Interestingly when I include bourbon `@import 'bourbon';` in a file that isn't declared in the sass-resources-loader it works. Perhaps ExtractTextPlugin doesn't pass the includePaths from sass-loader to modules referenced in sass-resource-loader.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive but I believe `includepaths` has to be an array, even if there's only 1 entry.

Also [`bourbon`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bourbon) and [`bourbon-neat`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bourbon-neat) are the official pagkages so you may have better luck with those and not `node-bourbon`.

Edit to clarify:

You would need to enter the following for the options →

```
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              includePaths: [require('bourbon').includePaths]
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. 

You're right that it needs to be an array but bourbon returns an array so that should be fine:

```module.exports = {
  includePaths: [
    path.join(__dirname, 'app/assets/stylesheets')
  ]
};```. I've managed to find a workaround for now so not to worry.